# SQL combine rows and create columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure

Sometimes the hardest thing is to know how to ask the right question, but I'm going to make an attempt.
I'm trying to figure out a SQL statement (I'm in Azure SQL) that will retrieve multiple rows, combine some of the columns and create new aliased column from other columns, all for each row returned from a larger select statement.
Clear as mud? Let me try to draw it out.

```
    Employees    
    ------------
    employeeID  |  managerID | fname
     1                 5        Bill
     2                 5        John
     3                 6        Mary


ClassRegistration
-----------------
employeeID   |  classID
  1               25
  2               25
  1               27
  1               28
  2               30
  1               45
  1               55
  2               35


Classes
----------
classID  |   classStartDate 
   25           7/1/2014
   27           7/14/2014
   28           7/28/2014
   30           7/11/2014
   35           8/1/2014
   45           8/1/2014
```

What I need to return is a table like this:

```
Employee fname  |  Last Class |  Upcoming Class 
 Bill                 27              28
 John                 30              35
```

So I would need something like:  Select * Employees WHERE managerID = 5.
Then using that result set of all employees with specified managerID, return the last class and the next class in one row for each employee returned.
Also an employee may or may not have a last class and/or upcoming class.

I've seen many different ways to iterate through rows using temp tables, or combining with GROUP BY, etc.  But I just can't seem to wrap my head around what combination I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better solution... use the `over` clause...

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.empId, E.managerid, e.fname,    
                Max(lastclass.classStartDate) over(partition by e.empId) as lastClass,
                Min(nextClass.classStartDate) over(partition by e.empId) as nextClass
FROM [T_employees] E
INNER JOIN T_ClassRegistration CR on E.empId = CR.empid   
LEFT JOIN T_Classes lastclass on CR.classid = lastclass.classid 
                             and lastclass.classStartDate <= getdate()
LEFT JOIN T_Classes nextClass on CR.classid = nextClass.classid 
                             and nextClass.classStartDate> getdate()
WHERE managerId = 5
```

Comment: this will give last and next class start date but the requirement is to return the class id.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the only way to solve it, but it's what came to my mind.  It requires two inner queries, one to obtain the last class and one to obtain the next class.

```
-- For testing the query, lets set hardcoded date.  Normally one might use GETDATE()
DECLARE @today DATE = '2014-07-16'

SELECT
  e.FName,
  (
    -- Get the class with the highest ClassStartDate which started before today
    SELECT TOP 1 c.ClassID
    FROM ClassRegistration cr
      INNER JOIN Classes c on c.ClassID = cr.ClassId
    WHERE cr.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
      AND c.ClassStartDate < @today
    ORDER BY ClassStartDate DESC
  ) AS LastClass,
  (
    -- Get the class with the lowest ClassStartDate which started after, or including, today
    SELECT TOP 1 c.ClassID
    FROM ClassRegistration cr
      INNER JOIN Classes c on c.ClassID = cr.ClassId
    WHERE cr.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
      AND c.ClassStartDate >= @today
    ORDER BY ClassStartDate ASC
  ) AS NextClass
FROM Employees e
ORDER BY FName
```

If you want to filter by employees which were registered in a previous class, then something like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    e.FName,
    (
      -- Get the class with the highest ClassStartDate which started before today
      SELECT TOP 1 c.ClassID
      FROM ClassRegistration cr
        INNER JOIN Classes c on c.ClassID = cr.ClassId
      WHERE cr.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
        AND c.ClassStartDate < @today
      ORDER BY ClassStartDate DESC
    ) AS LastClass,
    (
      -- Get the class with the lowest ClassStartDate which started after, or including, today
      SELECT TOP 1 c.ClassID
      FROM ClassRegistration cr
            INNER JOIN Classes c on c.ClassID = cr.ClassId
          WHERE cr.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
            AND c.ClassStartDate >= @today
          ORDER BY ClassStartDate ASC
        ) AS NextClass
  FROM Employees e
) t
WHERE NextClass IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY FName
```

Comment: thanks for the help!  I selected the other answer as best simply because it seems cleaner.

Comment: It's a better answer.  I didn't even think to use min/max as window functions.